# TcpListener in NodeJS

Tags: c#, node.js

I have a C# snippet that creates a simple TcpListener as following:

```
if (tcp == null)
{
    this.tcp = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), port);
}
this.tcp.Start();
listening = true;
while (listening)
{
    Socket mySocket = null;
    try
    {
        mySocket = this.tcp.AcceptSocket();
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        byte[] bReceive = new byte[1024 * 1024 * 2];
        mySocket.Receive(bReceive);
        Analysis(bReceive, mySocket);
    }
    catch
    {
        // ...
    }
}
this.tcp.Stop();
```

and it does works without any problem. I was trying to achieve the same thing in NodeJS, so I set up this code:

```
const net = require('net');

...

server = net.createServer();

server.on('connection', (socket) => {
    //This is never reached
    debugger;
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            analysis(data, socket);
        }, 500);
    });
});

server.listen(port, serverIP, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on', server.address());
});

server.on('error', (error) => {
  //...
});
```

The server starts correctly but that's all. The debugger statement is never reached.

What am I doing wrong?

- - - - EDIT - - - -

Additional information:

The IP set to this code is taken from the command `ipconfig /all` -> ethernet board (Since my computer is connected via the ethernet cable). The output IP is `10.0.0.11`.
As I said in a comment, the port doesn't really matter until is free and a not-used one. So I picked the `3500`.

*Note: Firewall is off, I don't have proxy set up nor something that can somehow deny a connection. As I said, the same IP and PORT lead to the Java program to work and the NodeJS to start, but no to receive any message / connection stuff*.

What's sending those messages is a clock named `S800/ID+W`. Sadly there isn't much to be found online, but I managed to ask some info to a person that works for that company. I've asked him the same question I'm asking here but he doesn't know how to do it. What I have is the clock's protocol doc (which doesn't matter since it's not about the TCP connection, rather how the clock send data to a custom implementation (which I have already done)), and an image on how to specify the client IP and PORT on which there must be a listening software for those messages.

This is the photo:

[image]

`Server address` is set to `10.0.0.11`

`Server port` is set to `3500`

Comment: you mentioned that the debugger statement is never reached. If that's the case, it's possible that no client is connecting to the server, or there might be an issue with the network configuration or the port and IP you're trying to listen on.

Comment: I believe it's more on how the TcpListener and the net operates. The client that tries to connect is just an instance on the same PC and it works perfectly when the Java program is up and running. As for now I've just accepted the fact to use Java to achieve that, but it would be amazing to understand why it doesn't work in Node

Comment: What is the `port` and `serverIP` values you are using? Also can you share the output of this statement `console.log('Server listening on', server.address());`. I am assuming its something to do with wrong address/IP and port binding.

Comment: Hi, IP and PORT are set to be the IP address of the computer and the port I choose is `3500`. I'll add the full log later. Besides, it's not a binding error since the same configuration in the Java code works fine.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi Ip address of computer could be internal or external. Can you please make sure its same address at both client and server end? In neither of your code can we see how the `serverIP` is being populated, thus just wanted to put your attention there.

Comment: I'll add more info to my question.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi thanks for updating the question. May I ask how are you connecting the clock to network? Direct cable (to PC) or Wifi?

Comment: You're welcome. Both PC and the Clocks are connected via cable to the same router.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254424/discussion-between-subdeveloper-and-jacopo-sciampi).

Answer (score 1):

I debugged this JavaScript file:

```js
const net = require('node:net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
    debugger;
    console.log('client connected');
    socket.on('end', () => {
        console.log('client disconnected');
    });
    socket.on('error', (err) => console.log(err));

    socket.write('hello ' + socket.address().address + '\r\n');
    socket.end(() => console.log('client disconnected by server'));
});

server.on('error', (err) => console.log(err));

server.listen(8124, () => console.log('server bound'));
```

#### Basic debugging steps:

1. Start a debug session executing `node inspect <filename.js>`.
2. Press <kbd>C</kbd> to continue the execution.
3. Send a request.

   - If you want to send a **HTTP request**, then open a command line interface (CLI) and execute `curl -v --http0.9  http://localhost:8124`.
   - If you want to send a **TCP request**, then open a CLI and execute `telnet 127.0.0.1 8124`.
4. The debugger stops at debugger statement.
5. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to jump to next method.

---

#### Example of Telnet client

I use this server implementation:

```js
const net = require('node:net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  console.log('client connected');
  socket.on('end', () => console.log('client disconnected'));
  socket.on('error', (err) => console.log(err));
  socket.on('data', (buffer) => console.log(buffer.toString()));
});

server.on('error', (err) => console.log(err));

server.listen(8124, () => console.log('server bound'));
```

Steps in telnet client:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to change the command prompt to show as `Microsoft Telnet>`.
- Type `send hello world from telnet client`. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to send to server.
- Type `quit` or `q` to close this client.

Example of output in server console:

```
server bound
client connected
hello world from telnet client
client disconnected
```

#### References:

- [The Node.js debugger client](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html)
- [TCP server](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#netcreateserveroptions-connectionlistener)
- [Enable Telnet on Windows 10 OS](https://www.makeuseof.com/enable-telnet-windows/)

---

As [@subdeveloper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1584623/subdeveloper) commented, there is a problem with IP binding. The default IP of server is `::` (IPv6), so it is `0:0:0:0` (IPv4).

Output when server is listening:

```
server bound:  { address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 8124 }
```

So you can define IP:

```js
server.listen({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 8124 },
  () => console.log('server bound: ', server.address()));
```

Output:

```
server bound:  { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 8124 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sadly the request sent it's not an HTTP one, but a plain TCP one. What actually is doing the request is a badge-clock that use the ZKTeco Push SDK

Comment: Added an example of TCP request.

Comment: Well, I tried to debug and inspect your code but same result. Of course the `telnet` request arrives just fine (even with my code on the question), but no messages from the actual machine that send them.

Comment: I added an example of Telnet client. I send a message to server and print it to the console.

Comment: I updated my answer according to subdeveloper comments.

Comment: Thank you for the support, I've added the results in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254424/discussion-between-subdeveloper-and-jacopo-sciampi)